# C# Windows Forms ListView Hyperlink

Tags: c#, listview

I have a listview with several columns and need to make the values of a specific column linkable (file share ex: \192.168.1.1\example\example.pdf). how can I acomplish this ?

thanks

Comment: Did you tried _anything_?

Comment: hottracking.. but it makes all the columns linkable (but doesn't go anywhere)

Comment: I suggest you to use [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) instead

Comment: you could handle the `ItemActivate` event along with hottracking

Comment: Isnt there a way to do this without having to use third party software ?